# Can we make payment with "Do direct method" Paypal using Card number, Amount and expiry date only in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented Paypal `Do direct method` in my site. its working fine.

But is this possible that i can do payments with only following parameters:

a) Amount,
b) Card number,
c) Expiry date

Please suggest..

Comment: Do you have tried to google it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the account was vetted when you got approved for Pro.  In most cases, you'll have access to Fraud Management Filters in your PayPal profile.  If you adjust those so that AVS and CVV2 do not require a match then you can process the card with just the amount, name on card, card number, and expiration date.

The DoDirectPayment API actually does require that you send a billing address, but you can just send bogus values for those params in cases where you don't actually have it.  The AVS would come back as a mis-match, but again, with the filters setup to accept that you'd be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i will check it according to it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your response. I have a one query.. Is there any other Paypal method available with that billing parameters not required.

Comment: No, they're going to require something for those values, but again, you can just send anything you want in cases where you don't have a true value.  I often use things like 123 N/A for a street, for example.  00000 for a zip code.  It'll work fine as long as your AVS settings don't block it.